# Android Applications force closed with error "deadbaad"

Tags: android, forceclose

I just update My Application in Play Store. In first 24-hours there's no crash error report. But, after that, a unique error reported. And this error make App force closed.

Here are the stack traces from Google Play Developer Console:

> ```
> pid: 5161, tid: 5406, name: Thread-45807 >>> milandro.blogs.uny.ac.id.historoid <<<
> signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaad
> Abort message: 'invalid address or address of corrupt block 0x61e4dc98 passed to dlfree'
> r0 00000000 r1 40134fea r2 deadbaad r3 40138b5e
> r4 61e4dc98 r5 40143190 r6 400f1000 r7 61e4dca0
> r8 00000000 r9 00000020 sl 00000002 fp 67f4eea9
> ip 00000001 sp 644979c0 lr 40106833 pc 40106834 cpsr 600f0030
> d0 2064696c61766e69 d1 2073736572646461
> d2 657264646120726f d3 6f6320666f207373
> d4 e42be0da81996cde d5 e316665881decb2c
> d6 554268d4f956bf32 d7 a2d34a7f1ce294fc
> d8 0000000000000000 d9 0000000000000000
> d10 0000000000000000 d11 0000000000000000
> d12 0000000000000000 d13 0000000000000000
> d14 0000000000000000 d15 0000000000000000
> d16 0000000000000000 d17 0000000000000000
> d18 48ee5947bb7be20c d19 3ea720d5ec195d37
> d20 63203ea720d5ec19 d21 2f4bd3cc2303919d
> d22 f0ffb8df8fe3a1d4 d23 172b0884ca7b0205
> d24 3ce47e5b39e23ec1 d25 bf56c087e80f1e27
> d26 3fe62e42fefa39ef d27 bfdffffffd0c5e81
> d28 39da3fc9ef8d6b7e d29 3ef99342e0ee5069
> d30 3fa55553e1053a42 d31 36d0cf8435b916ef
> scr 60000012
>
> backtrace:
> #00 pc 00011834 /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+1191)
> #01 pc 0000dcd3 /system/lib/libc.so (free+10)
> #02 pc 00083983 /system/lib/libcrypto.so (CRYPTO_free+34)
> #03 pc 0002f623 /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl_parse_serverhello_tlsext+738)
> #04 pc 000181b1 /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl3_get_server_hello+1008)
> #05 pc 000175af /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl3_connect+566)
> #06 pc 00027ecb /system/lib/libssl.so (SSL_do_handshake+50)
> #07 pc 0000aedd /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
> #08 pc 0002038c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
> #09 pc 00051007 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
> #10 pc 00029820 /system/lib/libdvm.so
> #11 pc 00030ca8 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
> #12 pc 0002e340 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
> #13 pc 000634e5 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
> #14 pc 00063509 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
> #15 pc 000581bb /system/lib/libdvm.so
> #16 pc 0000d238 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
> #17 pc 0000d3d0 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
>
> code around pc:
> 40106814 6a014478 62021e4a f7fdb95a e008fd39
> 40106824 4621482a 44784a2a f001447a 4a13f9b3
> 40106834 49286014 f8d14479 079a31bc f501d51c
> 40106844 e8bd70e0 f02c40f8 4823b801 f7fd4478
> 40106854 4822fd0d e7fa4478 42b7688f ae10f43f
> 40106864 481fe611 e7f24478 4478481e 6888e7ef
> 40106874 f43f4298 e606aed4 bf00bdf8 deadbaad
> 40106884 0003cdee 0003cde0 0003cd48 000326cc
> 40106894 0003ccbc 0003ccaa 0003cc32 0003cc10
> 401068a4 0003cbb4 0003cb9e 0003cb38 0003cb20
> 401068b4 0003cb0e 0003cab6 0003ca90 0003ca06
> 401068c4 0003c9b0 0003c996 0003c978 0002e7bc
> 401068d4 0003232e 0003c954 0003230a 00032302
> 401068e4 000322f2 000322ec 460db538 b1704601
> 401068f4 0200ea45 f405fb00 04030c10 4620b143
> 40106904 ee90f028 bf1842a8 34fff04f 4604e000
>
> code around lr:
> 40106810 482e61a3 6a014478 62021e4a f7fdb95a
> 40106820 e008fd39 4621482a 44784a2a f001447a
> 40106830 4a13f9b3 49286014 f8d14479 079a31bc
> 40106840 f501d51c e8bd70e0 f02c40f8 4823b801
> 40106850 f7fd4478 4822fd0d e7fa4478 42b7688f
> 40106860 ae10f43f 481fe611 e7f24478 4478481e
> 40106870 6888e7ef f43f4298 e606aed4 bf00bdf8
> 40106880 deadbaad 0003cdee 0003cde0 0003cd48
> 40106890 000326cc 0003ccbc 0003ccaa 0003cc32
> 401068a0 0003cc10 0003cbb4 0003cb9e 0003cb38
> 401068b0 0003cb20 0003cb0e 0003cab6 0003ca90
> 401068c0 0003ca06 0003c9b0 0003c996 0003c978
> 401068d0 0002e7bc 0003232e 0003c954 0003230a
> 401068e0 00032302 000322f2 000322ec 460db538
> 401068f0 b1704601 0200ea45 f405fb00 04030c10
> 40106900 4620b143 ee90f028 bf1842a8 34fff04f
> ```

**Have anyone solution to fix this ?**

Thank You.

Comment: I guess you should look at the 244355th bit there, it looks quirky ... Seriously, what are we supposed to tell you from this?

Comment: Well, did you ever get an error like this..?. For me, this is first time I got an error like this... really... :) :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

See:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74964

There is a possible solution that says:

We appear to have greatly reduced, if not eliminated this crash by adding a lock around the startHandshake() call (we haven't seen it since). Code is simply...

```
        synchronized(sHandshakeLock) {
            sslSock.startHandshake();
        }
```

Comment: I have absolutely no idea, you have not posted anything except your error. I don't even know if you use an SSL socket? If you do, I would start there, perhaps... The error is documented, and the above is a suggested solution, but there are other solutions too. It's pretty much up to you, but you have been pointed in the right direction. All I did was simply search for your error, you might try it and see if it helps? Hope I have helped.... :)

Comment: I do not use any SSL Socket in my code. But, I use Picasso Library to load some images from a site that uses SSL. Does it matter?

Comment: There are references to OKHttp as well, which may be an issue.

Comment: Yes, I use the version 2.5.2 which was the last version of Picasso. As what you say, in their Javadoc, I found "OkHttpDownloader - A Downloader which uses OkHttp to download images". Maybe that's where the problems occur. I'll try to handle Picasso when load an image from a site that uses SSL...

Thank you very much..,

Comment: I found this that might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31859282/ssl-certificate-pinning-w-picasso